# Unmatched Vlookup data from another workbook in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to create a master Excel sheet that takes the data from other Excel sheets by using the chassis number of the car as a primary key. I am using the `Vlookup` (`buscarv` in Spanish) function in Excel but I don't get the matching data that I want with the function:

```
=Vlookup(A2;'Listado Julio.xlsx'!Tabla5[#Todo]; 3)
```

Image showing the formula and the data that it is supposed to show:

[image: Formula and data]

Instead, the formula takes the last value of the matrix from where it is supposed to search from the answer.

Could somebody tell me what the formula is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell B2 you could also enter an INDEX MATCH function instead of the v-lookup. The INDEX MATCH can replace all v-lookup and h-lookup tasks and requires less processing power as Excel does not have to count the rows / columns.
In cell B2 enter:

```
=INDEX('Listado'!C:C,MATCH('Hoja1'!A2,'Listado'!B:B,0))
```

Then copy that formula down the column.

Comment: Thank you!! It works with this functions!!!! I think Vlookup was better suited for one book formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an exact match, you need to set the last optional argument of vlookup to False, so you your formula would be `=Vlookup(A2,'Listado Julio.xlsx'!Tabla5[#Todo], 3, FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to tell it exactly which columns to use:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Listado!B:C,2,0)
```

There might be some regional formatting differences. The last arg for me is 0, which means only return exact matches.